# How to split a text file on a delimiter into multiple files in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, text, split, ksh

I have a text file that looks like this:

input_file

```
1|abc
2|def
3|ghi
n|etc...
```

I need to split this up into two files on the pipe delimeter. So this is the expected output:

File_1:

```
1
2
3
n
```

File_2:

```
abc
def
ghi
etc
```

I do not know how many lines the input file will have. How do you achieve this in ksh or bash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk would be suitable for this task:

```
awk -F\| '{print $1 > "File_1"; print $2 > "File_2"}' input_file
```

This splits your text on the "|" and prints each column to the respective file.

If there were more than two fields, you may prefer to use a loop instead:

```
awk -F\| '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) print $i > "File_" i}' input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d '|' -f 1 input_file > File_1
cut -d '|' -f 2 input_file > File_2
```

Only with bash:

```
while IFS='|' read A B; do echo "$A" >>File_1; echo "$B" >>File_2; done <input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using other bash commands

```
cat input_file | cut -d '|' -f1 > File_1
cat input_file | cut -d '|' -f2 > File_2
```

Or you can put them together in one line

```
cat input_file | tee >(cut -d '|' -f1 > File_1) | cut -d '|' -f2 > File_2
```